# Check if a value is within a range in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, range

I am working on a Rails 3 application and need to display some test results in the following format:

```
TestLower     TestResult    TestUpper
1.1           1.5           2.0
```

What I would like to do, is give the result one css class if the value is within the Lower and Upper limit and then give it a different css class if the value falls outside of the range.

I have used if and unless statements before but this is a little more complicated because I need to compare one value against two others, rather than one value against one other.

The only way I can think of doing it would involve quite a few if statements and fallbacks. Such as 'if @lab.TestResult > @lab.TestLower' and then have another one the same that checks it's lower than the TestUpper.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Maybe a rails number helper of some form?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby also has [`between?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
if (value.between?(lower, higher)) 
   ...
```

You could use this in combination with the [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) helper in rails:

```
content_tag(:span, value, :class => value.between?(lower, higher) ? "between" : "not-between")
```

Comment: That look pretty handy! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do both checks in the same if condition:

```
lower, upper, value = ...
if value > lower and value < upper
  puts "In range"
else
  puts "Out of range"
end
```